# Which values of $k$ give a maximum at $x=-1$ for the following equation?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

A question from a university entrance exam says the following:

> Which values of $k$ give a maximum at $x = -1$ for $f(x) = (k + 1)x^4 - (3k + 2)x^2 - 2kx$?

It seems the question may have been [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165804/coefficients-of-a-quartic-polynomial-to-locate-a-maximum-at-x-1) but with a mistake in the given function.

My initial response was to calculate $f(-1)$, but this works out to be $-1$, with no $k$ involved to calculate a maximum.

Doesn't this mean that for any value of $k$, $f(-1)$ will always be $-1$, if so I don't understand how a maximum could be calculated for a variable which has no effect on the output.

This is probably a fundamental misunderstanding of the question by me.

Comment: The fact that f(-1)= -1 says **nothing** about it being a "maximum" or "minimum" or anything in between.

Comment: The misunderstanding could be "find the value of $k$ that gives the maximal value $f(-1)$" vs. "find the value of $k$ that makes $f$ have a maximum at $-1$". The former does not make sense here, as you point out. For the latter: How do you check for the maximum of a function? The answer is @MichaelRozenberg's comment.

Comment: @N.. That makes more sense.